# In Unity, why do I get a "does not implement right interface" error when trying to sort my list of objects?

Tags: unity, c#, sorting

I am trying to create a crafting panel that sorts the list of items you can make alphabetically, yet I cannot figure out why `.Sort()` is not working.

What I have is a game object that holds a list of all the items you can make and the requirements, then in my crafting script I access the game object for the list and display the info.

Everything works fine until I try to sort anything. `craftDatabase` is what I need to be sorted. Also, it needs to be sorted by `ItemID`.

---

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class CraftDatabase : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public List<Blueprint> craftDatabase = new List<Blueprint>();
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Blueprint
{
    public string itemId;
    public int itemAmount;
    public float itemCraftTime = 1f;
    public CraftPanel.subsections subsection;
    public CraftPanel.workstations workStation;
    public List<requiredItem> requiredItems = new List<requiredItem>();

    [HideInInspector]        
    public string desc;

    [System.Serializable]
    public struct requiredItem
    {
        public string itemId;
        public int itemAmount;
    }

    public Blueprint()
    {
    }
}
```

---

When I try to throw in `craftDatabase.craftDatabase.Sort();` it gives me this error:

> `ArgumentException: does not implement right interface`

How do I fix this error to use `Sort()`?

Comment: I updated it with the `craftdatabase` script

Comment: @Gnemlock We tolerate generic programming questions when they're in the context of game programming. I don't remember where the post about it was.

Comment: @Gnemlock Yeah, that's a while ago :) I've grown up since. I agree that the use should have searched google first, though.

Comment: I have asked on meta, and there *was* no change as per @AlexandreVaillancourt comment, but we *are* in the process of change. Ultimately, I have been so confident in the root of this question because I *know the answer*. I can also identify a fair amount of redundancy, in your question (we only need to see `Blueprint` to see why `Sort()` is not working) so as such, I am removing the additional examples to further clean up the question (debugging questions require a ***minimal*** viable example).

Answer (score 2):

Before we can use `Sort()`, we need to know how to sort between instances of the *type* we are using. The error is complaining that you *do not* have the required sorting functions, which are sought out through an `interface`.

An `interface` is basically a set of method signatures. Any class that *uses* that `interface` must implement the same methods. If you are unfamiliar with using interfaces, I suggest you follow [this Unity scripting tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/interfaces).

In this context, this allows us to take a *generic type* and *guarantee* that it can be sorted; we can write our own methods to handle comparing two instances.

---

According to [official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), you need to implement either `IComparable` or `IComparable<T>`. The key difference is that the inclusion of `<T>` makes the method *generic* and more adaptable. This also makes it more confusing, and it looks like we do not need to use *generics*, so let's use `IComparable`.

---

According to [official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable(v=vs.110).aspx), to implement `IComparable`, we only need to implement `CompareTo(Object)`. This method must return an `int` value, which represents the approximate compared order of the local `Object` and the `Object` that was passed in.

- If the local `Object` is greater, we need to return a **positive** number.
- If the passed in `Object` is greater, we need to return a **negative** number.
- If the two `Object` types are equal, we must return **zero**.

---

This actually becomes quite easy, in context. You want to compare a `String`, which should already implement a variation of `CompareTo()`.

To allow sorting in a generic list, your `Blueprint` class should look as follows:

```
class Blueprint : IComparable
{
    public string itemID;

    ...

    public override int CompareTo(Blueprint other)
    {
        return itemID.CompareTo(other.itemID);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please let me know if there are any problems. It's really hard to test this sort of thing, ATM.